# firstOption showing error in slick 3.0 and play 2.4

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, securesocial

I am integrating silhouette (a fork of securesocial) in my project as an authentication library so I am following it's example project with slick **play-silhouette-slick-seed**

While writing [these lines](https://github.com/sne11ius/play-silhouette-slick-seed/blob/master/app/models/daos/slick/UserDAOSlick.scala#L26-L46) I am getting lot of errors in eclipse.

```
def find(loginInfo: LoginInfo) = {
  DB withSession { implicit session =>
    Future.successful {
      slickLoginInfos.filter(
        x => x.providerID === loginInfo.providerID && x.providerKey === loginInfo.providerKey
      ).firstOption match {
        case Some(info) =>
          slickUserLoginInfos.filter(_.loginInfoId === info.id).firstOption match {
            case Some(userLoginInfo) =>
              slickUsers.filter(_.id === userLoginInfo.userID).firstOption match {
                case Some(user) =>
                  Some(User(UUID.fromString(user.userID), loginInfo, user.firstName, user.lastName, user.fullName, user.email, user.avatarURL))
                case None => None
              }
            case None => None
          }
        case None => None
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[*Errors are expected since example project is written with old releases of play and slick*]

I tried to migrate them so I replaced withSession with run and firstOption with headOption since I read in slick official doc that former ones have been deprecated in slick 3.0. Following are my changes but its still not working

```
def find(loginInfo: LoginInfo) = {
   DB run { 
     Future.successful {
        slickLoginInfos.filter(
          x => x.providerID === loginInfo.providerID && x.providerKey === loginInfo.providerKey
        ).result.headOption match {
          case Some(info) =>
            slickUserLoginInfos.filter(_.loginInfoId === info.id).result.headOption match {
              case Some(userLoginInfo) =>
                slickUsers.filter(_.id === userLoginInfo.userID).result.headOption match {
                  case Some(user) =>
                    Some(User(UUID.fromString(user.userID), loginInfo, user.firstName, user.lastName, user.fullName, user.email, user.avatarURL))
                  case None => None
                }
              case None => None
            }
          case None => None
        }
     }
  }
}
```

I am new to play and scala, just exploring new things everyday. Could you please help me out in fixing these errors. It would be appreciable if anybody can also explain me use of future values, how it is beneficial over normal values that we get using **Await (db.run(....))** and how to parse a value inside future object since I have seen at some places they use map and some places they use onSuccess or case, its pretty much confusing. What is best way to work with future values?

Answer (score 0):

Look up `joinLeft` which will use `Option` for the right (`joinRight` for the left) if nothing is matched. So, you'd want something like:

```
val q1 = for {
  (loginInfo, userLoginInfo) <- slickLoginInfos.filter(...) joinLeft slickUserLoginInfos on (_.id === _.loginInfoId)
} yield (loginInfo, userLoginInfo)
val q2 = for {
  ((loginInfo, userLoginInfo), user) <- q1 joinLeft slickUsers.filter(...) on (_._2.loginInfoId === _.id)
} yield {
   // use loginInfo, userLoginInfo and user are optional
}
```

The `userLoginInfo` and `user` there will be `Option` to be either `Some` or `None` depending on whether there was any match.  You run this `q2` and `headOption` on it for the overall result.

### Futures

Previously, you'd do something like:

```
dao.fetch().map(_.toString)
```

where `dao.fetch()` returns a `Seq[Int]`.  Now, with Slick 3.0, this would be `Future[Seq[Int]]` meaning you simply need another `.map` (or `flatMap`):

```
dao.fetch().map(_.map(_.toString))
```

which continues doing the same as before except that it's now wrapped in a `Future`. There are benefits in using `Future`s in that you don't need to block a thread for each and every call to the database.

Comment: Can't we do it without using joins ? Also in query q2 I am a little bit not clear what to write inside slickUsers.filter(.....)

Comment: In that case, you'd need to db.run() each time (just .result won't do it, unless you do join's).  Disadvantage of this is that you'd do three separate DB calls, whereas with a join you'd do only one DB call.

Comment: Thanks, I got that it would be slow. But could you please help me out in completing second query. I am just stuck here since _._2 is a type of option I am not able to apply === operator in that. I am learning slick don't know much about it.